# How do I create postgres case-sensitive role from windows terminal

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I try to create role `Abhishek` from windows terminal using the following command it creates a role `abhishek` which is not what I want.

`psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE Abhishek LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE;`

I want to create the role using terminal only as later I have to put this as a command in a script file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use quotes, Luke

```
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE ""Abhishek"" LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE;"
```

Identifiers in quotes are not normalized and used as-is.

References:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

PS: could you guys please teach me how you get the link to the latest documentation? :-) I cannot remember the link and every time I fail miserably finding it on the postgresql docs site.

Comment: In the online docs, click on "current" in the breadcrumb. So, the URL you pasted becomes https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: @IamIC indeed. In 2015 there was no such a link though (it was introduced relatively recently)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. We are fortunate now.